# Can't oracle19c use the ORACLE_SID environment variable to connect to the database?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a Pro*C file upgraded from Oracle10 to 19c (Oracle10 in Solaris10, 19c in Redhat8)

In Oracle10 I use "`proc USERID=aaa/bbb SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS ...`" to compile the .pc file, the proc will connect to the ORACLE_SID database, but when compiling the file in 19c, it reports "**PCC-02104Unable to connect to Oracle**" error, meaning The username or password is invalid. I changed the compile command to "`proc USERID=aaa/bbb@ccc SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS ...` " and tried again, and it was successful, because I used `@ccc` to specify the database name.

Does 19c not support using ORACLE_SID to connect to the database? If yes, is there any documentation about it?  this problem is just my test, no official instructions.

Thanks !

Comment: Is the `ccc` TNS entry (in your tnsnames.ora file) using a service name that points to a PDB, rather than a CDB?

Comment: Are you using a pluggable database? if not, then it should work. All versions I've used (up to 21c) support using ORACLE_SID. If you're using pdbs, then ORACLE_SID will just connect to the root and not the pdb.

Comment: @gsalem
hi, it may be the PDB, I created a test database, didn't select "create as container database" when installing, and it was fine.
Thank you for your reminder, i use of oracle is still in the 11g  :(

Comment: @AlexPoole    it may be PDB, now recreated the database, not using CDB or PDB, works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ORACLE_SID for a multientant architecture database will always take you to the CONTAINER instance.

Your data, your code will be in a pluggable database.

Oracle has advised for quite some time now that you always use the SERVICE to create your connections vs the SID - and that's for any type of database, not just multitenanted ones.

If you see this [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/connecting-oracle-database-xeinl.html), there's only references to the Service name, nothing on SID.

Comment: Thank you, I learned about PDB according to your reminders, maybe I didn't pay attention to these options when I created the database, so something went wrong, my way of using oracle is outdated, but it's working fine now, thanks again